Metamask wallet with solflare snap
I used metamask wallet
I created account with Private key I have private key
Metamask does not support Solana
I used my sol address for airdrop
I received $70 worth of borpa
Plz tell me procedure how I can use sol on metamask to trade borpa token
I snap metamask wallet with solfare
But it's showing wrong sol address
Plz help me
